# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, modelmapper

**APPLICATION FAILED TO START**

---

Parameter 1 of constructor in Kodlama.io.Devs.business.concretes.ProgrammingLanguageManager required a bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' in your configuration.

---

**ProgrammingLanguageManager**

```
@Service
public class ProgrammingLanguageManager implements ProgrammingLanguageService {

    @Autowired
    private ProgrammingLanguageRepository programmingLanguageRepository;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ProgrammingLanguageManager(ProgrammingLanguageRepository programmingLanguageRepository,
            ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.programmingLanguageRepository = programmingLanguageRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;

    }

    // * * * CRUD OPERATIONS * * *

    @Override
    public CreateProgrammingLanguageResponse add(CreateProgrammingLanguageRequest createProgrammingLanguageRequest)
            throws Exception {
        nameCannotBeSame(createProgrammingLanguageRequest.getName());

        ProgrammingLanguage programmingLanguage = modelMapper.map(createProgrammingLanguageRequest,
                ProgrammingLanguage.class);
        ProgrammingLanguage saveProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository.save(programmingLanguage);

        CreateProgrammingLanguageResponse createProgrammingLanguageResponse = modelMapper
                .map(saveProgrammingLanguageResult, CreateProgrammingLanguageResponse.class);

        return createProgrammingLanguageResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateProgrammingLanguageResponse update(UpdateProgrammingLanguageRequest updateProgrammingLanguageRequest)
            throws Exception {
        nameCannotBeSame(updateProgrammingLanguageRequest.getName());

        ProgrammingLanguage programmingLanguage = modelMapper.map(updateProgrammingLanguageRequest,
                ProgrammingLanguage.class);
        ProgrammingLanguage saveProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository.save(programmingLanguage);

        UpdateProgrammingLanguageResponse updateProgrammingLanguageResponse = modelMapper
                .map(saveProgrammingLanguageResult, UpdateProgrammingLanguageResponse.class);

        return updateProgrammingLanguageResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public DeleteProgrammingLanguageResponse delete(DeleteProgrammingLanguageRequest deleteProgrammingLanguageRequest) {

        ProgrammingLanguage getReferenceByIdProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository
                .getReferenceById(deleteProgrammingLanguageRequest.getId());
        programmingLanguageRepository.delete(getReferenceByIdProgrammingLanguageResult);

        DeleteProgrammingLanguageResponse deleteProgrammingLanguageResponse = modelMapper
                .map(getReferenceByIdProgrammingLanguageResult, DeleteProgrammingLanguageResponse.class);

        return deleteProgrammingLanguageResponse;
    }

    // * * * GET METHODS * * *

    @Override
    public List<GetAllProgrammingLanguagesResponse> getAll() {

        List<ProgrammingLanguage> findAllProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository.findAll();

        return modelMapper.map(findAllProgrammingLanguageResult,
                new TypeToken<List<GetAllProgrammingLanguagesResponse>>() {
                }.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public GetByIdProgrammingLanguageResponse getById(
            GetByIdProgrammingLanguageRequest getByIdProgrammingLanguageRequest) {

        ProgrammingLanguage getReferenceByIdProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository
                .getReferenceById(getByIdProgrammingLanguageRequest.getId());

        GetByIdProgrammingLanguageResponse getByIdProgrammingLanguageResponse = modelMapper
                .map(getReferenceByIdProgrammingLanguageResult, GetByIdProgrammingLanguageResponse.class);

        return getByIdProgrammingLanguageResponse;
    }

    public GetByNameProgrammingLanguageResponse getByName(
            GetByNameProgrammingLanguageRequest getByNameProgrammingLanguageRequest) {

        ProgrammingLanguage getReferenceByNameProgrammingLanguageResult = new ProgrammingLanguage();
        getReferenceByNameProgrammingLanguageResult = programmingLanguageRepository
                .getByName(getByNameProgrammingLanguageRequest.toString());

        GetByNameProgrammingLanguageResponse getByNameProgrammingLanguageResponse = modelMapper
                .map(getReferenceByNameProgrammingLanguageResult, GetByNameProgrammingLanguageResponse.class);

        return getByNameProgrammingLanguageResponse;
    }

    // * * * BUSINESS RULES * * *

    private void nameCannotBeSame(String name) throws Exception {

        ProgrammingLanguage programmingLanguage = programmingLanguageRepository.getByName(name);

        var result = programmingLanguage;

        if (result != null) {
            throw new Exception(Messages.NAME_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        }
    }
}
```

Im missing something but i don't know what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ModelMapper class is not registered as spring bean, it is just a normal java class.
In order to fix that, you need to create a `@Configuration` class that will define the bean if you'd like to autowire it.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you cannot use spring dependency injection and you would have to create the object yourself with `new ModelMapper();`

Another tip is to avoid annotating fields with `@Autowire`. Constructor level annotation is enough.

Comment: Why constructor level annotation is better than @Autowire?

Comment: Injecting beans through constructor allows you to easily mock these beans in testing, encouraging proper testing. Additionally, it will result in the cleaner design of your application, as you'll easily spot all the circular dependencies, which may be harder to spot with field injection.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error message that the `bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper'` is missing. So please add the following bean to your project and try again.

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

**Note :** *Add this bean in class annotated with `@Configuration`.*

Answer (score 0):

As My application is working without `@Configuration` annotation.So I'm supposing In **Spring Boot v3.0.1** there is no need for `@Configuration` annotation. `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in main class handles everything. **You just need `@Been` annotation method mentioned in the above answers**.